# Different size inputs in a multi column form

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm new to coding, and I'm struggling to make my inputs the size I need them to be.

I have a 6 column form, with all input boxes the same size. I would like some to be wider, and some to be narrower.

Everything I have tried to narrow the boxes causes the column to collaps

My HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Web Form</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>    
</head>

<body>

        <div id="header"><h1>LED Savings Calculator</h1></div>


        <div id="c1" class="column1" >

          <form room="input" action="#" method="post">

                  Room 1: <input type="text" room="" value="" ><br/> 
                  Room 2: <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                  Room 3: <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                  Room 4: <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                  Room 5: <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                  Room 6: <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                  Room 7: <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                  Room 8: <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                  Room 9: <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                  Room 10: <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>

            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="lights" class="column1" >
            <form lights="input" action="#" method="post">

                  Existing Lights: <input type="text" lights="" value=""><br/> 
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>

              </form>
        </div>
            <div id="Watts" class="column2" >

              <form watts="input" action="#" method="post">    
                  Lamp Size (Watts): <input type="text" lights="" value=""  ><br/> 
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""  ><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value="" ><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value="" ><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value="" ><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value="" ><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value="" ><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value="" ><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value="" ><br/>

              </form>
        </div>
  <div  id="Quantity" class="column2" >
    <form room="input" action="#" method="post">

                  How Many?: <input type="text" lights="" value=""><br/> 
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>

            </form>
        </div>
      <div  id="savings" class="column2" >
         <form room="input" action="#" method="post" >
           Costs: <input type="text" lights="" value=""><br/> 
                 . <input type="text" room="" value="" ><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
           </form>
        </div>


  <div  id="savings" class="column2" >
    <form room="input" action="#" method="post" >
         Savings: <input type="text" lights="" value=""><br/> 
                 . <input type="text" room="" value="" ><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
                 . <input type="text" room="" value=""><br/>
           </form>
        </div>
```

And CSS is:

```
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#header {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  background-color: #00A0B0;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  height: 40px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Myriad-pro;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
 }

div.column1 {
  float:left;
  width:150px;
  height:400px;
}

div.column2 {
  float:left;
  width:150px;
  height:400px;
}
```

Comment: In your `<input/>`, what's the `room` attribute for?

Comment: It doesn't need to be there, to create the columns I c & p'ed to save time.
Once I have the layout correct I will amend the attributes and jscript

Answer (score 0):

you can change their `size` attribute.

plus their is no `room` attribute. i don't know what you are trying to do.
you can't make random attributes up.

```
<input type="text" size="5" value="" >
<input type="text" size="10" value="" >
```

etc.

here is demo http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/a8Urj/

Comment: Many thanks. 
When I enter the sizes this way I lose all 'justification'.
The boxes below raise up which brings everything out of alignment. 

I need the 'rooms' to be wide for input such as 'living room' but things like 'quantity' only need space for a few digits such as '3'

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle example.

Comment: Am struggling to paste the code into jsfiddle - this is becoming very embarrassing!!

Comment: are you trying to have everything on the same row?

Comment: @Steve in your "no size", add `div.column2 input{ width:50px; }`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're defining table width with CSS at the bottom, you can adjust that!

Have you tried adding width into each text input?

Comment: When I do I lose all 'justification'.
The boxes below raise up which brings everything out of alignment. 

I need the 'rooms' to be wide for input such as 'living room' but things like 'quantity' only need space for a few digits such as '3'

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input type="text"  value=""  style="Width:50px" >
<input type="text"  value=""  style="Width:100px">
<input type="text"  value=""  style="Width:70px">
```

change the value as you need it

Comment: You missed '=' i.e. style="Width:50px"